# What is wrong with my array?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, failovercluster

I cannot figure out what i need to fix to get the script to run.

The code:

```
$clusterNodeNames = (Get-ClusterNode -Cluster Clu05).Name
$AllVMsInCluster = Get-VM -ComputerName $clusterNodeNames

$AllVMs = $AllVMsInCluster | Select -ExpandProperty Name

$AllVMsInCluster[1] | Set-VM -SnapshotFileLocation C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\$AllVMs[1]
```

What is happening is i am creating two arrays

```
$AllVMsInCluster

$AllVMs
```

Output of:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $AllVMsInCluster[1]

Name     State CPUUsage(%) MemoryAssigned(M) Uptime   Status             Version
----     ----- ----------- ----------------- ------   ------             -------
acd-pv06 Saved 0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally 8.0

PS C:\Windows\system32> $AllVMs[1]
acd-pv06
```

My end game is to put the last line in a loop however at the end I keep getting the whole array.

When i run the last line it will change the SnapshotFileLocation for only acd-pv06 but the output looks like:

```
C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\acd-pv02 acd-pv06 acd-SQL01-ag acd-SQL02-ag[1]
```

How i can i get it to look like:

```
C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\acd-pv06\
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need two arrays. You already have the `.Name` property available to you within the objects in the `$AllVMsInCluster` array. Use it directly in the loop or pipeline. Wrap the object.property in a sub-expression `$()` to ensure correct variable expansion.

```
$AllVmsInCluster |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Changing snapshot file location for $($_.Name)."
        Set-VM -VM $_ -SnapshotFileLocation "C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\$($_.Name)" -WhatIf
    }
```

Remove `-WhatIf` when you're ready to perform the changes for real.